# Looping through an array and displaying data

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am trying to loop through an array and display that. The problem I've got is that for some reason only the ID is being displayed. I've gone through and debugged and can't understand why this doesn't work. All the data I want to process is available as I've checked through debugging and logging out the array.

Here is the HTML to display:

```html
<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
  <p *ngIf="carsArray.length < 1">No cars are available</p>
  <ul class="list-group" *ngIf="carsArray.length >= 1">
    <li class="list-group-item" *ngFor="let car of carsArray">
      <p>{{ car.id }}</p>
      <p>{{ car.type }}</p>
      <p>{{ car.manufacturer }}</p>
      <p>{{ car.colour }}</p>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Here is my typescript that retrieves said data.

```js
fetchData() {
  this.http
    .get<{ [key: string]: car }>(
      'actual URL goes here'
    )
    .pipe(
      map((ResponseData) => {
        const carsArray: car[] = [];
        for (const key in ResponseData) {
          if (ResponseData.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            carsArray.push({ ...ResponseData[key], id: key });
          }
        }
        return carsArray;
      })
    )
    .subscribe((post) => {
      this.carsArray = post;
      console.log(this.carsArray);
    });
}
```

Here is a what I'm currently getting:
[image: https://i.imgur.com/hOCo7UE.png]

Any help would be appreciated as I'm completely stumped!

Comment: So you're doing `{ ...ResponseData[key], id: key }` and only seeing `id` ... coud you `console.log(ResponseData[key])` just before the `push` ... maybe the data is in a sub object ?

Comment: Would you mind providing the sample response object? whats getting inside `carsArray`?

Comment: @SélimAchour I logged `console.log(ResponseData[key]);` and this is what I get: https://i.imgur.com/8qSJ0En.png so the array looks okay to me

Comment: @sunnyprakash this is my cars object if that's what you mean?
`export interface car {
  manufacturer: string;
  colour: string;
  type: string;
  id?: string;
}`

Comment: I see `Colour` and you're trying `colour` ... case mismatch ?

Comment: @SélimAchour where are you seeing upper case Colour. It looks to be the same everywhere for me.

Comment: @TomCockram in the png you provided

Comment: @TomCockram i saw the image you have provided. there, keys are capitalized, but the interface which you have given all are in lowercase. maybe case issue.

Comment: Yeah this is screenshot from the firebase database I'm using and for some reason when I submit the data they're uppercase!!! https://i.imgur.com/g1lFvR2.png

Comment: Basically you're getting { Colour: ..., Type: ...} and you're printing .colour and .type. Just change `<p>{{ car.type }}</p>` to `<p>{{ car.Type }}</p>` and see if that fixes the issue

Comment: .................................. So I changed my types inside the model to have upper case and they're all displayed. Thanks guys!!! I just couldn't work out what was wrong

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to change my model file to have upper case types. The data that was being submitted to the database was in uppercase...

```
export interface car {
  Manufacturer: string;
  Colour: string;
  Type: string;
  id?: string;
}
```